# Python Gtk Table, “button.grab.default” misbehaving

Tags: python, button, gtk

I am having trouble setting a default button for a gtk table in a window.

It is a 4x3 table, and I want to set the center button to be the default.

I have the center button set as default, but it is not behaving correctly when I move it with the arrow keys.

Please check out my code at: http://dpaste.com/3M36W8X

The center button is set as default button at line 118 At lines 189 and 190, if I switch "self.window.show()" with "self.table.show()" the buttons behave correctly, but I can't default a button.

The way it is set now, the center button is set as default initially, but as soon as I move with the arrow keys, it acts as though there wasn't a default key to begin with.

Please let me know if I can describe this problem better!

Comment: "as soon as I move with the arrow keys, it acts as though there wasn't a default key to begin with" -- what does this mean exactly? By the way, the 'On Hold' message you got the previous time you posted this question did give you advice on what you should do to improve the question, please follow that advice here.

Comment: Hey there jku, I know I'm sorry, I'm honestly trying my hardest to explain it the best way I can, but it's a bit hard to explain it.

So let's say button 5 is the default. The button to the right is button 6, and when I press the right arrow key (from button 5), I expect the "focus" to be on button 6. However, this doesn't happen, and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thanks for the response, -Eric